# Jquery bug in Android Chrome

Tags: android, jquery

I have the below jquery which is working fine on desktop browsers, when I load it on an android mobile chrome and when I start typing, the second letter goes before the first letter and others follows the second letter.

[Here is an image how its working...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik6mo.jpg)

Can anyone help me solve this out please?

```
 $("#textbox").on('input', function(evt) {
          if(this.lengh == 0) return $(this);

          var input = $(this);
          var start = input[0].selectionStart;
          $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 +:%=\\/-]/gi,""))
          $(this).val(function (_, val) {
            return val.toUpperCase();
          });
          input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;
        });
```

Comment: Have you trying removing **input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;** what's that for? 
https://jsfiddle.net/5j03zhsb/

Comment: That is for while you writing if yo decide to modify any letter in the middle of the sentence, cursor stays where u type...

Comment: Sorry if I ask, but if you remove it, will the code works on android? And anyway, you can just use **input[0].selectionEnd = start** instead of **input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;**

Comment: Yes if I remove that part, it works fine, but you can only type 1 letter at the middle and cursor goes back to the end of the sentence...

Comment: Have you tried using **input[0].selectionEnd = start** instead of **input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;** ?

Comment: I just try it, still the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when, in Android, the selectionStart is zero.

Test it with your phone: http://www.vixed.it/st/34947263/

```
$("#textbox").on('input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $(this);
    var start = input[0].selectionStart;
    var inputTextChanged = input.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 +:%=\\/-]/gi,"").toUpperCase();
    input.val(inputTextChanged);
    if (start>=1) input[0].selectionEnd = start;
});
```

Comment: This time its doing the same error for the second letter... But first letter is working fine

Comment: I really don't know, I mean in on my phone works fine.

Comment: Can you please test it on www.vixed.it/t.html with your phone?

Comment: still same problem with your link too, this problem only occures if you are using mobile chromei if you are using any other browser, it works fine...

Comment: I'm using mobile chrome, I'm editing my answer, and I've updated my link. Can you please test it again, for me it's working.

Comment: I've edited my answer again and tested it on a old android version with chrome.

Comment: Me and a friend of mine have tested it on 3 different android phones with chrome browser, and it works. Sorry, but I really don't know why is not working on your device. My thought is that you are using a custom keyboard on it instead of the Android default, but it's just a thought.

Comment: I thing it could be because of region, mine is turkish and some of my friends are having the same issue, I dont know why but chrome's java libraries are different for different regions...

Comment: can I please ask you to test it on your phone removing the **replace** part of code?

Comment: http://www.vixed.it/st/34947263/1/ 
but are you testing my link or I can stop doing it?